# How to enforce https from htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, resin

I have to enforce https everytime when the sign-in site-node is loading.
For example http://www.mysite.com/sign-in should always be enforced to https.

I tried multiple versions but none of them worked. It's the first time when I am using .htaccess

here is what i tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} sign-in
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /sign-in
RewriteRule !(.*)lbping(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `%{REQUEST_URI}` and `$1` together in rewritten URL.

You can try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule sign-in https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried that also, and it's still not working. Could be because there are some request params after sign-in?

Comment: No params don't matter. Can you directly visit `https://site.com/sign-in` in the browser?

Comment: Then make sure this .htaccess and mod_rewrite are enabled and this rule is first your after `RewriteEngine On`